# REGEX for date format Jun 12 2011 12:00:00:000AM

Tags: php, regex

Just a quick one, what's the best REGEX to pick out dates of this format:

Jun 12 2011 12:00:00:000AM

Months are always 3 letters and days are also 2 digits.

Comment: If you want to know this to parse dates, you could try [`strtotime`](http://ca3.php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/\w{3} \d{2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}(AM|PM)/i
```

To capture part of it just add some parthensis whenever you need

If you need to validate a string of course don't use REGEX but http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Comment: You'll probably want to add a few capture groups.

Comment: @zneak: he didn't ask for it, but yes he can add whenever he needs

Comment: @yes123 as asked, but your regexp matches something like `XXX 99 9999 99:99:99:999AM` as well :-)

Comment: Yes, that is technically correct. Not specific enough though for the JSON I'm parsing.

Comment: @frederik: he can use something like gregoriandate to valided the string before giving it to the regx. Anyway you are absoluty right +1

Comment: @yes123 worst spelling of my name so far ;-)

Comment: This is more what I'm aiming for /(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) ([0-9]{0,2}) ([0-9]{4}) 12:00:00:000AM/i

Comment: @Ben: do you need to validate it or do you need to extract values? If you need to validate there is no need to use REGEX: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Comment: I'm trying to do this but failing miserably: $output = preg_replace("/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) ([0-9]{0,2}) ([0-9]{4,}) 12:00:00:000AM/i", formatdate("$1/$2/$3"), $output);

Comment: And doing stuff like $date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date)); with little success.

Answer (score 1):

try this (untested)

```
/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) ([0-3]\d) ([12][09]\d{2}) ([01]\d):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d):(\d{3})(AM|PM)/
```

Comment: for the year, I believe you want (?:20)|(?:19). Otherwise you could have 1066 or 2934.